# Capistrano upload fails with incorrect arguments error?

Tags: capistrano

I'm running

```
upload('bin/rvm_install.sh','~/rvm_install.sh')
```

in my Capistrano deploy script. And it's spitting out the following error:

```
capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task': wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Changing

```
upload('bin/rvm_install.sh','~/rvm_install.sh')
```

to

```
top.upload('bin/rvm_install.sh','~/rvm_install.sh')
```

solved my problem.

Comment: +1 That helped me to use capistrano `run` command from the namespaced task